# How to find the asymptotic bit cost

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

I know from a general point of view what big O notation is. I have taken an algorithms class before that was all implementations and did well. I am now in an algorithms class that is mostly theory and I cannot answer a basic question...

Assume that the cost of multiplying two numbers is $M(n) = O(n^2)$, analyze the asymptotic bit cost of the equation...

$$
\frac{(.1 + \sqrt{4})^k}{.2}
$$

I came up with $O(kn^2 + 1024)$ since they are 32 bit floats and I have to do $k$ multiplications plus 1 more for the division. This answer seems dumb though and I am pretty sure it is wrong. How would you answer it?

Comment: How would you calculate x^k when k = 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 etc. ? How many multiplications do you need? And for example x^100 = x^64 * x^32 * x^4.

Comment: I don't quite follow your comment, I need an arbitrary amount of multiplications, which is specified by k, and each multiplication takes O(n^2) by the definition of the problem

Comment: What you might be missing is that the statement probably meant "Assume that the cost of multiplying two **n-bit** numbers is O(n^2)". So the time complexity of the multiplication depends on the number of bits of its operands. Also, as hinted by @gnasher729, you do not need $\Omega(k)$ multiplications.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: It depends.  Are you trying to compute the exact value of that expression, or a floating-point approximation?  (It's not an equation.  There is no equality sign.)